# Reading huge ascii text file quickly in Java. Need help using MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, performance, filereader, memory-mapped-files

I have a text file with thousands of lines of data like the following:

```
38.48,88.25
48.20,98.11
100.24,181.39
83.01,97.33
```

... and the list keeps going (thousands of lines just like that).

I figured out how to separate this data into usable tokens using **FileReader** and **Scanner** but this method is far too slow.

I created the following delimeter:
src.useDelimiter(",|\n");

and then used the scanner class nextDouble() to get each piece of data.

I have done a lot of research and it looks like the solution is to use a **MappedByteBuffer** to place the data into memory and access it there. The problem is I don't know how to use MappedByteBuffer to separate this data into usable tokens.

I found this site: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/memorymapped-file-and-io-in-java.html - which helps me to map the file into memory and it explains how to read the file but it looks like the data is returned as a byte or perhaps in binary form? The file I am trying to access is ascii and I need to be able to read the data as ascii as well. Can anyone explain how to do that? Is there a way to scan a file mapped into memory in the same way that I have done using scanner with the previous FileReader method? Or is there another method that would be faster? My current method takes nearly 800x the amount of time that it should take.

I know some may say I am trying to reinvent the wheel but this is for **academic purposes** and thus, I am not allowed to use external libraries.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to keep all the data in memory or just read it line per line.

Comment: I need to read it line per line to query the data. Currently this process takes about 40 seconds to process nearly a million lines of data, but I need this done faster. If I could do it in less than a second that would be great.

Comment: I would suggest doing a single pass on the data on initialization and storing it on an appropriate structure in memory. Then the access to the data will be fast and you won't need to be concerned about the speed at which you can read.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. I don't have any experience doing this though. How can I get this data into memory and stored into a structure containing doubles?

Comment: See if wrapping your FileReader in a BufferedReader improves performance.

Comment: dnault: If wrapping my FileReader in a BufferedReader is as simple as declaring: "BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(fileIn);" and then changing my scanners source to stdIn then the performance remains the same. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data loaded into memory you can use the Scanner in the same way you did earlier, then store each row on a list like the following.

```
List<Pair> data = new ArrayList<Pair>();
```

Where Pair is defined as

```
class Pair {

  private final double first;
  private final double second;

  public Pair(double first, double second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }   
  ....
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this structure but I can't figure out how to assign data to this structure. I tried: data.add(double, double) but that doesn't work. I tried creating a set method within the Pair class but it won't let me since "first" and "second" are declared as "final". I know I could change this but I do want them to be final values. So how do I add an item to this list?

Comment: Answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504569/adding-arraylist-items-to-a-user-defined-class-with-final-values-in-java

Comment: This still takes the 40 seconds to load all of this into memory, but once it's there I can run subsequent searches on this data much faster. Before it would take 40 seconds for each search. Thank you for this suggestion! Is there any way to load this into memory faster?

Comment: At this point, if all you are doing is reading fron the file into the data structure, the speed will depend mostly on the size of your data file and the speed of your storage devices.

Answer (score 0):

`MappedByteBuffer` is a subclass of [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) on which you can call `asCharBuffer`. That returns a [`CharBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) which implements `Readable`, which can then be supplied to [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.Readable%29).

That way you can use `Scanner` on the file via `MappedByteBuffer`. Whether that makes it perform any faster I don't know.