# Adding ArrayList items to a user-defined class with final values in Java

Tags: java, class, loops, arraylist, final

I have a text file with thousands of lines of data like the following:

```
38.48,88.25
48.20,98.11
100.24,181.39
83.01,97.33
```

I can separate each "double" value just fine, but I'm having trouble adding each line to my user-defined class. In my main method, I created a list by:

```
List<Pair> data = new ArrayList<Pair>();
```

Where Pair is defined as:

```
class Pair {

  private final double first;
  private final double second;

  public Pair(double first, double second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }
```

Now I'm trying to add items to this list. I tried: "data.add(double, double)" but that doesn't work. I tried creating a set method within the Pair class but it won't let me since "first" and "second" are declared as "final". I know I could just change them but I do want them to be final values. So how do I add an item to this list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have declared the `List` as `List<Pair>`,you need to add `Pair` objects to that `List`. You need to create an instance of `Pair` passing the double values to its constructor and then `add` the instance to the `List<Pair> data`.Like this :

```
Pair pair = new Pair(doubleValue,doubleValue);
data.add(pair);
```

Please go through the documentation of `List`, it provides you two `add` methods to add elements to the `List` individually.

[add(E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) and [add(int index,E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,E)).

Comment: This works! Thank you! Also, I had to change my "class Pair" to "static class Pair" to avoid complaints from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Noob has mentioned. List or any other collection in java does not work on primitives. Collections store objects. So you need to create the object of your class pair, which will hold the details of first and second attribute. You can store multiple line of read file represented by Pair object in your list as:

```
List<Pair> data = new ArrayList<Pair>();
Pair pair = new Pair(first,second);
data.add(pair);
```